Airflow Clearing Tasks
I am running structured spark streaming job and using EmrContainerOperator to trigger the spark job.
My requirement is to re-trigger airflow task which has been created using EmrContainerOperator every time the task fails. This needs to be achieved programmatically.
Intention is to create infinite loop and re-trigger the task every time it fails. How this can be accomplished? I am using Airflow verion 2.7.2
I see options to re-trigger DAG, but my requirement is to re-trigger tasks every time it fails.

What are your constraints ? A DAG is not meant to run infinitely. You should create a DAG that runs every X minutes to first check the status of your Streaming job and relaunch it if needed.

I understand DAG is not meant to run infinitely. Constraint is EmrContainerOperator is submitting structured streaming spark job which fails after running a week or so due to memory issues. There is no option change spark jobs and every time job fails, we have to manually clear airflow task and re-submit the job. To avoid manual effort, I am trying to see options to re-trigger the task automatically.

Airflow is primarily made to execute tasks on a regular basis. One solution would be to restart your Job every week, before it fails. Another solution would be to check its status every 15 minutes and act accordingly. Check this similar question.
